# Dateadd function not doing half hour increments

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code:

```
worksheet1.Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, DURATION_COLUMN - 1) = Format(DateAdd("h", worksheet1.Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, DURATION_COLUMN), worksheet1.Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, DURATION_COLUMN - 2)), "hh:mm AM/PM")
```

The code is attempting to add the value at worksheet1.Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, DURATION_COLUMN), which is a long value to the value at worksheet1.Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, DURATION_COLUMN - 2), which is a date/time value, and attempting to add a number of hours.

The code works fine, unless the value at worksheet1.Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, DURATION_COLUMN) is 2.5; in which case it adds only 2 not 2.5. How to add 2.5 hours to the value at worksheet1.Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, DURATION_COLUMN - 2) ?

Comment: You will need to convert it to minutes and add those. `DateAdd("n",date/time,2.5*60)`

Comment: While the `number` parameter is marked `As Double` in the "Quick Info", the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateadd-function) states: "If number isn't a Long value, it is rounded to the nearest whole number before being evaluated."